# item.tolowercase is not a function in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, ionic3

When writing the name of the building in the searchbar the ionic returns me this error `item.tolowercase is not a function in ionic` 
How should I proceed to correct this detail?

This is a image example

[image: example]

This is `home.ts`

```
  export class HomePage {

  searchQuery: string = '';
  items: object[];
  constructor() {
      this.initializeItems();
  }

  initializeItems() {
    this.items = [
      { nome:'Abaeté', rua:'Rua Andira - 396', imagem:"assets/img/4Wj6RBrjQPGiTMhV6T9W_Abaete.JPG" },
    ];
  }

  getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    const val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's better you add actual text for error instated adding image for it, Please take some time to read the help page, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `item.toLowerCase` ... console.log(item) just before that call ... it is either undefined or not an object.

Comment: As you can see in `initializeItems`, your `items` are not strings, but objects...

Comment: Why did you deny my question? What error does she present to me? I put the code, explained the error and added an image as an example ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the items to string-

```
    return (item.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1);
```